# How to customise HTML5 video player controls on Firefox?

Tags: css, html, firefox, html5-video

I know there is a way to customize the native html5 player control?
I want to add a "cursor: pointer; " effect on the progress bar.

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

this code works in Chrome but not on Firefox, can anyone know how to apply the CSS setting? I have tried "-moz-media-controls-timeline" already

Comment: There is no Shadow-dom access in FF yet. So you can't like that. What you could do however is to build yourself your own controls.

Comment: Also, building your own controls will allow you to have more cross browser compatibility and consistency across browsers if you want do customizations like the one you mentioned here.